# City specific Google Trends results? Google Trends API pyGTrends malfunction

Tags: python, api, google-trends

I'm doing a research for a model where I'm looking at product sales behavior in different markets(cities). Which is why getting just the national search numbers aren't that useful. Is there any way for developers access the regional numbers from an API?

> I researched pyGTrends, but that module isn't working on my python 2.7.5. It gives me the following error:
>   No local packages or download links found for pyGTrends
>   error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyGTrends')
>   It would be helpful if you could tell me why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: I have come to believe that the person who owned the package removed it from his/her Github repository, is that valid ?